# Disregard letter when finding substring - Swift

Tags: swift

How do you make a letter count as another when finding a substring in Swift? For example, I have a string:

> I like to eat apples

But I want to be able to make it where all instances of 'p' could be written as 'b'.

If the user searches "abbles", it should still return the substring "apples" from the quote. I have this issue because I want whenever a user searches

> اكل

But the quote contains

> أكل

it would return that value. I tried `fullString.range(of: string, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]` but this does not fix it since the "ء" are not diacritics, so أ إ ا all behave differently when they should all be the same. Users only use ا. How do I make it count for أ and إ without replacing all instances of them with ا?

Comment: sounds like a variation of Longest common sub sequence problem  https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Longest%20Common%20Subsequence

Comment: @MjZac no that is unrelated

Comment: I would use a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a small String extension that uses simple regular expressions (as matt suggested in the comments) to do the actual matching. Like so:

```
extension String {
    func contains(substring: String, disregarding: [String]) -> Bool {
        var escapedPattern = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: substring)
        for string in disregarding {
            let replacement = String(repeating: ".", count: string.count)
            escapedPattern = escapedPattern.replacingOccurrences(of: string, with: replacement)
        }
        let regEx = ".*" + escapedPattern + ".*"

        return self.range(of: regEx,
                          options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
"I like apples".contains(substring: "apples", disregarding: ["p"]) //true
"I like abbles".contains(substring: "apples", disregarding: ["p"]) //true
"I like oranges".contains(substring: "apples", disregarding: ["p"]) //false
```